# Error when importing a GCP Bigquery table with Pyspark

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, databricks

I aim to import a table from Google Bigquery into my Python workflow using pyspark to take advantage of distributed systems, but when trying to import I get an Py4JJavaError error.

Have someone managed to import Bigquery tables into pyspark dataframes directly?

I've been trying to import a table from GCP Bigquery into my python workflow using the client object of the Google API as follows:

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

```
# Create credentials object using end-user keys
user_info = {"client_id": "XXX", "client_secret": "XXX", "refresh_token": "XXX"}
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(user_info)

# Create Bigquery client
client = bigquery.Client(project=f"gcp-project-name", credentials=credentials)
```

Making a direct query as follows:

```
query_string = "SELECT * FROM <my table>"
results = client.query(query_string).result()
```

or

```
results = client.query(query_string).to_dataframe()
```

works fine but not performant. Therefore I tried using pyspark as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
    .option('credentials', client._credentials.to_json()) \
    .option('table', f"my-bigquery_table") \
    .load()
```

but I get the error below that I don't fully get it

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o685.load.
: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: {
  at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryCredentialsSupplier(BigQueryClientModule.java:46)
  while locating com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier
    for the 3rd parameter of com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryClient(BigQueryClientModule.java:63)
  at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryClient(BigQueryClientModule.java:63)
  while locating com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient

1 error
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1097)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1131)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelationInternal(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:80)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:222)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: {
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decode(BaseEncoding.java:218)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:106)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.createCredentialsFromKey(BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.java:71)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.<init>(BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryCredentialsSupplier(BigQueryClientModule.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule$$FastClassByGuice$$b1b60333.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:264)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:65)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1094)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: {
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Alphabet.decode(BaseEncoding.java:492)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$Base64Encoding.decodeTo(BaseEncoding.java:972)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decodeChecked(BaseEncoding.java:233)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decode(BaseEncoding.java:216)
    ... 41 more
```